# can't write ñ, ä, ë, ü in a ubuntu docker container

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, utf-8

I need to be able to write ñ, ä, ë, ü in the console of an ubuntu docker container.
I created the image which I create the container from with the following dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:17.10
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install locales
RUN locale-gen es_CO.UTF-8 
ENV LANG es_CO.UTF-8 
ENV LANGUAGE es_CO:en 
ENV LC_ALL es_CO.UTF-8
```

If I run a python script like this:

```
print("ñ")
```

the ñ is printed in the console normally, the problem is when I try to write the letter ñ as an input of a a program, when I type ñ in the keyboard what shows up in the console is ¤. I have already tried to reconfigure the keyboard with setxkbmap but I get an error that says: 'Cannot open display "default display"'.

I also have tried to find a docker ubuntu images with this settings already setted but I have not finded any one. Please help.

Comment: What is the output if you execute `echo -n ñ | od -h` in the console (i.e. check with which bytes ¤ is represented by the console)?

Comment: Can you type ñ if you first type Ctrl-V followed by ñ?

Comment: I can't directly execute `echo -n ñ | od -h` as I am not able to type ñ, but I make a python script called a.py with this code `print('ñ')` and execute `python a.py | od -h` and the output was `0000000 b1c3 000a
0000003`. The output of executing echo -n ¤ | od -h is: `0000000 a4c2
0000002`. @weibeld

Comment: Typing Ctrl-V followed by ñ doesn't works. @weibeld

Comment: I also just realise that if I copy the string ñaäeöo and pase it in the console what it shows up is ¤a„e”o. @weibeld

Comment: So, your terminal can correctly decode UTF-8 characters. The problem must be in the input method. What is the output of `locale`?

Comment: this is the output of locale: ``LANG=es_CO.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=es_CO:es
LC_CTYPE="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=es_CO.UTF-8`` @weibeld

Comment: `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` missing?

Comment: @danihp the problem is not with the python script, the problem is with ubuntu

Comment: did you found the answer for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal seems to be correctly set up with UTF-8, and it is able to decode UTF-8 codes. The problem must be in the communication from the keyboard to the terminal.

Create the file `~/.inputrc` with the following content:

```
set input-meta on
set output-meta on
set convert-meta off 
set enable-meta-key on
```

Then, log out, log in again, start a new terminal, and see if it works.

Comment: it doesn't work, I also think that the problem have todo with the keyboard, do you know any way to change the destribution of the keyboard? @weibeld

Comment: So, when you paste ñ in the terminal, instead of typing it, does it work?

Comment: pasting ñ in the terminal instead of typing it doesn't works either. For example if I paste "ñ" in the terminal what terminal shows is "¤", but if I paste "¤" what terminal shows is "I¨", it's really weird. @weibeld